# what are the different reasons which might cause "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms"

Tags: apache-kafka

when I'm trying to publish a message onto a Kafka topic, sometimes I'm getting below error and have below questions

Error:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms

Questions:

1. what's this metadata update?
2. Who is trying to update the metadata and why is it failing after 60000 ms?
3. what is this 60000 ms?

Comment: How are you trying to publish the messages; can you share your code? Where are your Kafka brokers, are they local?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. The topic was not created when I tried to publish the message, once the topic is created, the issue is resolved. Thanks